# Link multiple XML files to be viewed in a PHP

Tags: php, ajax, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I was wondering is it possible to link multiple XML files so it can be displayed in a single PHP file?

I have multiple XML files, and wanted to know is there any particular code that can be used to link all the documents together without the need to combining all the XML files together?

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT you can use the [`document` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) in your code to read in additional files e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file1.xml')//foo | document('file2.xml')//foo | document('file3.xml')//foo"/>
```

processes the `foo` elements in those three files.

If you have a file listing all input documents in the form of e.g. `files.xml` with

```
<files>
  <file>file1.xml</file>
  <file>file2.xml</file>
  <file>file3.xml</file>
</files>
```

then

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document(document('files.xml')//file)//foo"/>
```

processes the `foo` elements in all files listed in the `files.xml` document.